# Manifolds, Vector Fields and Foliations

Tags: manifolds, dynamical-systems, vector-fields, diffeomorphism, foliations

Let $M$ be a **Manifold**, $X$ be a **Vector Field** on the manifold $M$ and $F$ be a **Foliation** of the manifold $M$.

When is the vector field $X$ **tangent** to the foliation $F$?

Comment: 1st should say $X$ is tangent to the foliation $F$

Comment: All three definitions are very straightforward, could you guess what they mean?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I am so sorry, for me they are not straightforward. Therefore, I would be very grateful if they were able to be explained.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I would be very grateful if you were able to help me out.

Comment: @janmarqz I edited my question as you have mentioned above. Is it possible now, for you, to help me out?

Comment: I wrote some as an answer, I hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A foliation $F$ of a manifolds $M$ is a decomposition of $M$ into
submanifolds $S$ (called the *sheets* of $F$) that are of dimension less of the dimension of $M$ and that a vector field $X$ be tangent to the sheets of the foliations: if $p\in S$ then $X(p)$ is in the tangent space $T_pS$.

Comment: You mean the vector field $X$ is tangent to the foliation if and only if it is tangent to each sheet of the sheets of the foliation.

Comment: yes, I am saying that... if $p\in S_1$ then  $X(p)\in TpS_1$ and if $q\in S_2$ then  $X(q)\in TpS_2$ and so on.

Comment: @Neilhawking: The same definition applies to your question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4175738/when-is-the-subset-n-is-tangent-to-the-vector-field-x?noredirect=1#comment8666329_4175738), just there you have a single submanifold.